# Having trouble parsing Json in Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

im getting the error: ** Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 24 path $.result** still trying to get my good path with it, i tried some other way but i still cant get to work.

**this is my json example:**

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "result": [
    {
      "league_key": "1",
      "league_name": "Superliga",
      "country_key": "1",
      "country_name": "Albania",
      "league_logo": "https://allsportsapi.com/logo/logo_leagues/1_superliga.png",
      "country_logo": "https://allsportsapi.com/logo/logo_country/1_albania.png"
    }  
  ]
}
```

**here you can see the model that i did using json2pojo**

```
public class LeaguesResponse implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Integer success;
    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> result = new ArrayList<>();
    public final static Parcelable.Creator<LeaguesResponse> CREATOR = new Creator<LeaguesResponse>() {


        @SuppressWarnings({
                "unchecked"
        })
        public LeaguesResponse createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new LeaguesResponse(in);
        }

        public LeaguesResponse[] newArray(int size) {
            return (new LeaguesResponse[size]);
        }

    };

    protected LeaguesResponse(Parcel in) {
        this.success = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
        in.readList(this.result, (com.pedrovs.leaguestandings.model.Result.class.getClassLoader()));
    }

    public LeaguesResponse() {
    }

    public Integer getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Integer success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(success);
        dest.writeList(result);
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
```

**Result Class**

```
public class Result implements Parcelable
{

    @SerializedName("league_key")
    @Expose
    private String leagueKey;
    @SerializedName("league_name")
    @Expose
    private String leagueName;
    @SerializedName("country_key")
    @Expose
    private String countryKey;
    @SerializedName("country_name")
    @Expose
    private String countryName;
    @SerializedName("league_logo")
    @Expose
    private String leagueLogo;
    @SerializedName("country_logo")
    @Expose
    private Object countryLogo;
    public final static Parcelable.Creator<Result> CREATOR = new Creator<Result>() {


        @SuppressWarnings({
                "unchecked"
        })
        public Result createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Result(in);
        }

        public Result[] newArray(int size) {
            return (new Result[size]);
        }

    }
            ;

    protected Result(Parcel in) {
        this.leagueKey = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.leagueName = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.countryKey = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.countryName = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.leagueLogo = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.countryLogo = ((Object) in.readValue((Object.class.getClassLoader())));
    }

    public Result() {
    }

    public String getLeagueKey() {
        return leagueKey;
    }

    public void setLeagueKey(String leagueKey) {
        this.leagueKey = leagueKey;
    }

    public String getLeagueName() {
        return leagueName;
    }

    public void setLeagueName(String leagueName) {
        this.leagueName = leagueName;
    }

    public String getCountryKey() {
        return countryKey;
    }

    public void setCountryKey(String countryKey) {
        this.countryKey = countryKey;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public String getLeagueLogo() {
        return leagueLogo;
    }

    public void setLeagueLogo(String leagueLogo) {
        this.leagueLogo = leagueLogo;
    }

    public Object getCountryLogo() {
        return countryLogo;
    }

    public void setCountryLogo(Object countryLogo) {
        this.countryLogo = countryLogo;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(leagueKey);
        dest.writeValue(leagueName);
        dest.writeValue(countryKey);
        dest.writeValue(countryName);
        dest.writeValue(leagueLogo);
        dest.writeValue(countryLogo);
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
```

**DataService :**

```
public interface LeagueDataService {
    @GET("api/football/?&met=Standings&leagueId=28&APIkey=78a1a6057999d384189812cf1f9e331e11cd1d0610eccb1b39e384efaf6056df")
    Call<LeaguesResponse> getAllLeagues();

}
```

**The method in the MainActivity**

```
 private void getAllLeagues() {

        LeagueDataService leagueDataService = RetrofitInstance.getService();

        Call<LeaguesResponse> call = leagueDataService.getAllLeagues();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<LeaguesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LeaguesResponse> call, Response<LeaguesResponse> response) {
                LeaguesResponse leaguesResponse = response.body();

                if (leaguesResponse!=null && response.body()!=null){
                    leagueList = leaguesResponse.getResult();
                    showRecyclerView();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LeaguesResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.i("MyTest" , t.getMessage());

            }
        });



    }
```

**I already tried to pass the Result activity to Call as a List, any help is good thank you!**

Comment: take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821497/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-when-using-gson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@SerializedName("country_logo")
@Expose
private Object countryLogo;
```

countryLogo Variable String, not Object.

```
@SerializedName("country_logo")
@Expose
private String countryLogo;
```